# window.location.href hash navigation for jquery mobile not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, hash

javascript:

```
function changeView(newViewDiv){
    window.location.href = "#"+newViewDiv;
}
```

and in different places of my javascript code I use this function to navigate through different jquery mobile pages 
eg:-

```
<div data-role="page" id="addpage">...</div>
```

to view the above page I use changeView('addpage') in my js code.
This works well in chrome, safari, firefox etc. but not working with internet explorer. url of the browser changes to http://example.com/index.html#addpage but page not displaying. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: When/How is the method being called? What version(s) of IE?

Comment: in jQuery Mobile you should navigate pages using the pagecontainer widget change method:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change,   $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + newViewDiv, { transition: "slide" });

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to ezanker's comment problem solved.
[window.location.href hash navigation for jquery mobile not working with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651160/window-location-href-hash-navigation-for-jquery-mobile-not-working-with-internet?noredirect=1#comment47446003_29651160)

**Answer:** 
in jQuery Mobile you should navigate pages using the pagecontainer widget change method: api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change,

`$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + newViewDiv, { transition: "slide" });`

–  ezanker

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used `window.location= url;` for mobile browser and its works successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You can try any of this

```
window.location= "#"+newViewDiv;
```

or

```
document.location = "#"+newViewDiv;
```

also be sure that your `newViewDiv` parameter has its value correct

Comment: have also tried that but no luck. parameter values are all good and working well with other browsers.